# Js function pass multiple parameters as a single object

Tags: javascript

I have the following constructor:

```
var one = new HB.hideShowFacilites.Selectors(".facilities .more-centered", "more-centered", "less-centered", "container-max-height", ".facilities .container-min-height");
```

Is there a way of passing all of these selectors as a single object?

```
HB.hideShowFacilites = HB.hideShowFacilites || {};

HB.hideShowFacilites.Selectors = function(sel1, sel2, sel3, sel4, sel5){
    this.sel1 = sel1;
    this.sel2 = sel2;
    this.sel3 = sel3;
    this.sel4 = sel4;
    this.sel5 = sel5;
};

HB.hideShowFacilites.Selectors.prototype.hideShow = function(){
    var $obj1 = $(this.sel1),
        $obj2 = this.sel2,
        $obj3 = this.sel3;
        $obj4 = this.sel4,
        $obj5 = $(this.sel5);

    $obj1.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if($obj1.hasClass($obj2)){
            $obj1.removeClass($obj2).addClass($obj3);
            $obj5.addClass($obj4);
        }
        else{
            $obj1.removeClass($obj3).addClass($obj2);
            $obj5.removeClass($obj4);
        }      
    });

};

$(document).ready(function(){

    var one = new HB.hideShowFacilites.Selectors(".facilities .more-centered", "more-centered", "less-centered", "container-max-height", ".facilities .container-min-height");

    one.hideShow();
});
```

Comment: send as an array `[".facilities .more-centered", "more-centered", "less-centered", "container-max-height", ".facilities .container-min-height"]`

Comment: what is HB.hideShowFacilites.Selectors() looking for?

Comment: not clear enough, do you want to pass values into function  as one object, or work with passed arguments as they are one object, or both, pass and process arguments as they are one object?

Comment: Instead of passing a long list of selectors, is it possible to pass them as a single object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible in pure JS to pass in function with argument list an object with members to be treated as arguments, without modifying function like this:

```
HB.hideShowFacilites.Selectors = function(selectors){
    this.sel1 = selectors.sel1;
    this.sel2 = selectors.sel2;
    this.sel3 = selectors.sel3;
    this.sel4 = selectors.sel4;
    this.sel5 = selectors.sel5;
};
```

function like this expect one argument and treat it as object with sel1, sel2 etc fields.

But in reverse it is possible to use passed argument list as array inside a function like this:

```
HB.hideShowFacilites.Selectors = function(sel1, sel2, sel3, sel4, sel5){
    this.sel1 = arguments[0];
    this.sel2 = arguments[1];
    this.sel3 = arguments[2];
    this.sel4 = arguments[3];
    this.sel5 = arguments[4];
};
```

futhermore, if you do not like modify that function, it is possible to redefine it using something like this

```
HB.myHideShowFacilites = function(){};

HB.myHideShowFacilites.prototype = HB.hideShowFacilites;

HB.hideShowFacilites.Selectors = function(selectors){
    this.sel1 = selectors.sel1;
    this.sel2 = selectors.sel2;
    this.sel3 = selectors.sel3;
    this.sel4 = selectors.sel4;
    this.sel5 = selectors.sel5;
};
```

and then use HB.myHideShowFacilites instead HB.hideShowFacilites

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how `HB.hideShowFacilites.Selectors` is implemented, you could use [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) like this

```
function foo(args) {
    var instance = Object.create(HB.hideShowFacilites.Selectors.prototype);
    HB.hideShowFacilites.Selectors.apply(instance, args);
    return instance;
}

var one = foo([".facilities .more-centered", "more-centered", "less-centered", "container-max-height", ".facilities .container-min-height"]);
```

---

From your edit of how it's defined, this method should work.

Comment: I find this too complicated.. Is there a way of defining an object with the selectors and than passing that object as a parameter for "var one = new HB.hideShowFacilites.Selectors"?